# Why does sending ^D with netcat not trigger an EOF when reading from a Unix socket?

Tags: sockets, unix, rust

I am trying to write a server that will read from a Unix socket:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixListener, UnixStream};

fn main() {
    let socket_name = "socket";

    let listener = match UnixListener::bind(&socket_name) {
        Err(err) => panic!("Failed to bind to socket: {}.", err),
        Ok(stream) => stream,
    };

    for mut stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(ref mut stream) => {
                let msg = read(stream);
                stream.write_all(msg.as_bytes()).expect("Echo");
            }
            Err(err) => panic!("Error occured when listening from the stream. {}", err),
        }
    }

    fn read(stream: &mut UnixStream) -> String {
        let mut s = String::new();
        stream.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
        s
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e76888a4ba6885f89467229021ca7ca2))

On the client side I use `nc`: `nc -U socket`. I send some data and end it with <kbd>^D</kbd> which should be an EOF. The docs for `read_to_string` say:

> Read all bytes until EOF in this source, appending them to buf

Expected behavior:
After sending <kbd>^D</kbd> on the client side the server responds with echo

Observed behavior:
Server doesn't recognize that EOF was sent and blocks. Only when the client breaks the connection the server prints the message and `panic`s with the broken pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I send some data and end it with <kbd>^D</kbd> which should be an EOF

It is, to the input of `nc`. That doesn't mean that the socket itself is closed:

> When netcat is faced with an EOF on its standard input, it may or may
>   not close the sending part of its TCP connection, depending on which
>   version of netcat it is.
>
> - [Solved: netcat (nc) doesn’t terminate at end of transmission](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2018/07/netcat-nc-stop-quit-disconnect/)

> **ctrl+d which sends an EOF on netcat's stdin**: netcat noticed the EOF. It will send no further data through the socket. However, it
>   continues running and reading from the socket in case the server has
>   more data to send.
>
> - [Unix : Epoll, catch ctrl+d and ctrl+c in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981790/unix-epoll-catch-ctrld-and-ctrlc-in-server)

For what it's worth, I cannot reproduce your problem on macOS 10.14.1  with the system-supplied `nc`.

You might be able to use the `-q` or `-w` options for your version of `nc`:

> Assuming that after sending EOF connection will stay idle, you can use `-w timeout` option, which works for `timeout` being equal to zero
>
> - [netcat doesn't terminate when stdin closes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189454/netcat-doesnt-terminate-when-stdin-closes)

You could also try being non-interactive:

```
$ echo 'hello' | nc -U socket
hello
```

See also:

- [read_to_end method never returns for UnixStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50818660/155423)
- [Reading from a TcpStream with Read::read_to_string hangs until the connection is closed by the remote end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30552187/155423)

Comment: That is the worst answer I could think of - my Rust code was fine and I lost half of the day trying to fix it.

Comment: It worked when I called it like: `nc -q 0 -U /tmp/socket` .

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue.  Try the `nc -N` flag.

This flag causes `nc` to send a shutdown(2) of the TCP socket when the input reaches `EOF`.

On an older version of Ubuntu (verified on 14.04), it behaved as though `-N` was always passed (and `nc` did not support `-N`).

On newer versions (verified on Ubuntu 20.04), it only exhibits this behavior when the `-N` flag is set.