# Select/Sockets: How to catch a CTRL+D input with no data before?

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm working with sockets and select to check if a client disconnected I check the return value of `recv` after a call to `FD_ISSET` like this:

```c
if (FD_ISSET(cl_fd, &fdset_rd)) {
    char buf[RECV_BUFSIZE + 1];
    int rd_ret = recv(cl_fd, buf, RECV_BUFSIZE, 0);
    if (rd_ret <= 0) {
        // client disconnected
    } else {
        // handle message from client
    }
}
```

So it works fine, even when I input `CTRL+D` in `netcat` after some data it successfully reads from the socket, but the only case where it seems broken is when I input `CTRL+D` directly with no data in front: in this case `FD_ISSET` doesn't return true and even when I send some input after the `CTRL+D` the socket seems to be in a "dead state", the client is still connected but the server can't receive any data.

Which is weird because when I input for example: `hello^Dhello`, the server successfully reads the first `hello` and the second, but when I input `^Dhello` it doesn't work.
The logical behavior should be to receive 0 characters and disconnect the client but I receive nothing and the client stays connected but becomes unreadable.

Here's a minimal reproductible example to see the problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define RECV_BUFSIZE 2048

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int sockfd;
    int cl_fd[__FD_SETSIZE];
    size_t cl_cnt = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(2130706433), // 127.0.0.1
        .sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]))
    };
    fd_set fdset_all = { };
    fd_set fdset_rd;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1
    || bind(sockfd, (void*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1
    || listen(sockfd, 32) == -1)
        return 1;
    FD_SET(sockfd, &fdset_all);

    while (true) {
        fdset_rd = fdset_all;
        if (select(__FD_SETSIZE, &fdset_rd, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
            return 1;

        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &fdset_rd)) {
            cl_fd[cl_cnt] = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
            if (cl_fd[cl_cnt] == -1)
                return 1;
            printf("client arrived (socket %d)\n", cl_fd[cl_cnt]);
            FD_SET(cl_fd[cl_cnt], &fdset_all);
            ++cl_cnt;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < cl_cnt; ++i) {
            if (FD_ISSET(cl_fd[i], &fdset_rd)) {
                char buf[RECV_BUFSIZE];
                int rd_ret = recv(cl_fd[i], buf, RECV_BUFSIZE, 0);

                printf("recv returned %d (socket %d)\n", rd_ret, cl_fd[i]);
                if (rd_ret <= 0) {
                    printf("client left (socket %d)\n", cl_fd[i]);
                    FD_CLR(cl_fd[i], &fdset_all);
                    close(cl_fd[i]);
                    cl_fd[i] = cl_fd[--cl_cnt];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Launch this program, then launch `nc localhost <port>` and try writing `hello^Dhello`: both `hello` are received by the server.

then try writing just `^D`: nothing is received, and if you try to send other messages after that nothing will be received as well, but when you `CTRL+C` in `nc` after that the client disconnection still gets received

Comment: If FD_ISSET does not return true on socket close then either your code path is wrong (i.e. wrong fd, does not reach this code ...) or the peer did not actually close the socket. Unfortunately, the small code fragment you show is not sufficient to reproduce and understand what you describe. Please produce something that actually can be used to understand the full problem - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note that Ctrl-D as a soft end-of-file signal is a feature of the terminal driver, not an inherent property of that character, and handling of its effect would be, in this case, up to `nc`.  The `nc` docs say that it recognizes such signals and handles them by closing the connection, but your description of the behavior, especially the behavior you characterize as working correctly, is not consistent with that.  I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: The problem is not your server but your client. netcat does not close the socket on ^D, nor does it send the ^D. Use `nc -N` - see [Why does sending ^D with netcat not trigger an EOF ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634911/why-does-sending-d-with-netcat-not-trigger-an-eof-when-reading-from-a-unix-sock)

Comment: Okay, I had doubts that it came from netcat, thanks for confirming it